# Angular reactive forms: bind value to formcontrolname

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am unable to get value in my output.
This is part of my dynamic form

```
<div [formGroupName]="i">
<div formArrayName="projects">
    <div *ngFor="let project of comp.get('projects').controls; let j=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="j">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-6 col-form-label">
                            <b>{{comp.value.serviceItemName}} {{j}}</b>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <!-- <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"> -->
                            <input formControlName="count" type="number" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Add {{comp.value.serviceItemName}}" />
                            <input formControlName="subling_flag" type="number" [value]="j" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The value is automatically set using the index in ngfor. I am unable to get the value as output. But if I change it the value is there in the output.

This is my data output structure

```
   {
    "serviceId": 1,
    "service_item_id": 987654,
    "serviceItemName": "test demo",
    "checkListId": "1736",
    "projects": [
        {
            "count": "",
            "subling_flag": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

below is my input field

```
<input formControlName="subling_flag" type="number" [value]="j" class="form-control" />
```

I want my output structure to be

```
{
    "serviceId": 1,
    "service_item_id": 987654,
    "serviceItemName": "test demo",
    "checkListId": "1736",
    "projects": [
        {
            "count": "1111",
            "subling_flag": "1"
        },{
            "count": "2222",
            "subling_flag": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<input formControlName="subling_flag" type="number" value="{{ j }}" class="form-control" />`

Hope it helps. Cheers

Here is the working sample from stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbqtmj

Comment: thanks for the answer. But the value is set in a loop. I get the value if I change it. but the field will be hidden so I dont have option to change it

Comment: how do i get the value of {{j}} in the output